# Is it possible to combine context state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm building an app that has some complex state  and I'm trying to handle that state using React Hooks. So I need multiple context providers like that:

```
export default function Provider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {});

  const update = useCallback(payload=> {
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE, payload});
  }, []);

  return (
    <TestContext.Provider
      value={useMemo(() => {
        return {
          state,
          update
        };
      }, [state, update])}
    >
      {children}
    </TestContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The state is composed of 2 objects, each of which contains multiple objects.

```
state: {
  inputs: {N objects}
  outputs: {M objects}
}
```

The data is fetched and updated from multiple different sources, so in order to keep the code clean I want to split the context providers into multiple providers and still have one state with all `inputs` and `outputs` that are the result of all provider's states.

Any ideas and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use several Context, you could also wrap the Providers.